# Can the function Beep() from Win damage my Audio card?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio

So, i made this little function which will read the Frequency and duration of notes from a .txt file and play the notes, that way i can play some little tunes. But from time to time, when playing them, some of the notes will sound super weird, like distorted. Clearly something wrong. So i was afraid that, since the Beep() function from windows was not written with that purpose, using it to play songs could damage my Audio Card. Can something like that happen? Here is the function i am using,

```
int PlaySong()
    {
        ifstream File("\Text.txt");
        if (File.is_open() == false)
            return -1;
        int F = 0;
        int D = 0;
        while (File.eof() == false)
        {
            File >> F >> D;
            Beep(F, D);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) is not from DirectX, it's a Windows function.

Comment: You are completely correct. Fixing my question right away.

Comment: The page at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has some history, as well as lots of user experience including several reports of issues with the sound (e.g. getting no sound for <80ms durations, clicking every second)...

Comment: The Beep() function is not drastically worse than a Metallica song, it cannot damage your audio card.  It traditionally produces a square-wave signal, the steep edges produces lots of un-even harmonics, the kind that sound grating to a human ear.  Kinda the point of beeping the user, the aural equivalent of a mild electrical shock to wake the user up.  It is completely inadequate to reproduce natural sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - no.  If the sound is not correct, it is probably down to the sound card driver or perhaps out-of-range parameters.

You have not revealed your input data, but very short time periods with rapidly changing frequencies is likely to be less than musical, and generate uncontrolled harmonics from incomplete cycles of the tone. This is especially true when the period is less than 1/F, but any abrupt frequency switch will introduce a discontinuity that will produce harmonics, and doing this rapidly will be clearly audible.

It seems that Beep() is clearly well defined to work with sound-cards since Windows 7 at least; prior to that it will have either not been supported, or will have driven the speaker directly from the timer chip.

From [MSDN Beep documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A long time ago, all PC computers shared a common 8254 programmable interval timer chip for the generation of primitive sounds. The Beep function was written specifically to emit a beep on that piece of hardware.
> On these older systems, muting and volume controls have no effect on Beep; you would still hear the tone. To silence the tone, you used the following commands:
>
> **net stop beep**
>
> **sc config beep start= disabled**
>
> Since then, sound cards have become standard equipment on almost all PC computers. As sound cards became more common, manufacturers began to remove the old timer chip from computers. The chips were also excluded from the design of server computers. The result is that Beep did not work on all computers without the chip. This was okay because most developers had moved on to calling the MessageBeep function that uses whatever is the default sound device instead of the 8254 chip.
>
> Eventually because of the lack of hardware to communicate with, support for Beep was dropped in Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition.
>
> In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the client.

Comment: any reason why you are duplicating paragraphs?

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks - shaky hands on the ctrl-v perhaps? - Had not had coffee yet.

Answer (score 2):

No it wouldn't damage the sound card if you are using the frequency of the sound, in hertz. in the range 37 through 32,767 (0x25 through 0x7FFF).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can damage any hardware with that, even if the function was not written for the purpose your audio card will have a wide frequency range. Although there is a possibility to damage attached speakers by playing a very low frequency often :).

Comment: +1, but re "possibility to damage" it's basically if the speakers are driven beyond the amplifier's or their own power rating (and yes low frequencies require more power for perceptually similar volume).